# How to use http/2 protocol when request the API v.3 in Openproject.org

Tags: angular, api, hateoas, openproject, ketting

I using the Angular to request API v.3 in Openproject.org with "ketting" library https://github.com/badgateway/ketting/wiki/Optimizing. But can not switch http/1.1 to http/2 protocol although changed HTTP -> HTTPs for Openproject.
[image]

Comment: http/2 is a server side setting. You can not switch from angular to http/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing! Thank Thorsten Rintelen so much! Your info solved my problem that lasted for about two weeks.
I was enabled http/2 for the apache webserver ( according to the guide on the web: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache/ after enabling https in server-side)

[image]

====> This article is solved!